# Eclipse content assist broken, show only java.lang.Object-methods

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

The content-assist do not work anymore.

The compiler can resolve the method `getGraphics()` but the Content-Assist can not.

Any idea how to fix the content-assist?

[image]

I tried to create a new workspace, no success.

Eclipse's workspace log is unremarkable.

Comment: This is just for the java.awt classes. See the duplicate for how to turn off the filtering that causes this.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes this solved my problem.